# Question regarding functions

Tags: general-topology

I have two questions regarding continuous functions.

$(1)$ Does there exist a continuous surjection $f:[0,1) \to [0,1]$?

$(2)$ Does there exist a continuous surjection $f:[0,1] \to [0,\frac 12]\cup [1, \frac 32]$?

I intuitively believe the answers to both of these questions are no, but I am not sure how to show it.

Comment: $f(x) = \min{1.5 x, 1}$

Answer (score 4):

The answer to 1 is in fact "yes". Remember that the function doesn't have to be injective. We can map $[0, \frac{1}{2}]$ continuously onto $[0, 1]$, then just do something with $(\frac{1}{2}, 1)$ - like keep it constant. Such an $f$ might be $f(x) = 2x$ if $x \leq \frac{1}{2}$, and $1$ otherwise.

The answer to 2 is indeed "no". That's because of the theorem that "the continuous image of a connected set is connected".